# Why doesn't bottle return lists?

Tags: python, json, bottle

*(Note: this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293979/how-do-i-return-a-json-array-with-bottle), I voted to close it as such but it may never happen so I prominently place the info here as I never know if the yellow informational banner about a possible duplicate is seen by everyone or just me)*

I would like to return a JSON representation of a list using `bottle`:

```
import bottle

def ret_dict():
    return {
        "who": {"name": "John"}
    }

def ret_list():
    return [
        {"name": "John"}
    ]

app = bottle.Bottle()
app.route('/dict', 'GET', ret_dict)
app.route('/list', 'GET', ret_list)
app.run()
```

Calling `http://127.0.0.1:8080/dict` returns `{"who": {"name": "John"}}` and `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`. This is OK.

Calling `http://127.0.0.1:8080/list` returns a `500`:

> Error: 500 Internal Server Error Sorry, the requested URL
>
> 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/list' caused an error:
>
> Unsupported response type: < class 'dict' >

There is no error nor traceback on the Python console.

At the same time a list can be serialized to JSON:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps([{"name": "John"}])
'[{"name": "John"}]'
```

**Why does `bottle` raises an error when trying to return a `list`?** (and happily returning a `dict`)

Comment: ask Bottle author why he did so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bottle's JSON plugin can only return objects of `dict` type - not `list`. There are vulnerabilities related to returning JSON arrays - see [this post about JSON hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/).

As a workaround you may wrap the `list` object under `dict` with some key say, *data* as:

```
def ret_list():
    my_data = [
        {"name": "John"}
    ]
    return {'data': my_data}
```

Also read [Vinay's answer to *"How do I return a JSON array with Bottle?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12294213/2063361).

Comment: Thanks. I am also marking my question as a duplicate.